# What to teach first: How to recognize numbers or letters?

Tags: toddler, education

I want to teach my 3-year-old daughter to recognize letters. She already knows how to count 1-10. And she understands when I tell her to give me one, two or three items.

Now I want to give her a game of A,B,C and start by letting her recognize just the A letter.

The question is: Before teaching her A,B,C should I start by teaching her 1,2,3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At three, your child can do both without confusion. **You** identify them and she'll pick up on it. You say something like, "This is the number 1." "Here is the (upper/lowercase) letter A/a."  You show her when you find the letters or numbers you are working on, or print the letter/number. She might even like to try printing or tracing the number. We played "I Spy" when we could. "I spy with my little eye -- a number (a letter) can you tell me which one it is?" If there were more than one letter or number, that helped the game feel like a game. Soon, our daughter was saying it back and we were looking for letters or numbers, too.

So, it is not necessary to start with letters or numbers first, but it is a good idea to say what they are. "Here is a number three/ or  here is a letter B."

Sing the Alphabet Song and perhaps "This Old Man" for numbers. Say, "This is the Alphabet Song. It is about all of the **letters**." [LINK to song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj4Dk89_Zlw) "This is the song about counting **Numbers**. [LINK to song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TloSQdGOop8)

There are other number and alphabet songs. Music really helps make learning fun and easier to remember. (I still sing ABC to myself if I need to know letter placement.)